# How to implement a mysql date or datetime field correctly in hook_schema()?

Tags: hooks, datetime, entities, database

I have written a mymodule.install file which contains a schema definition to create a table in my database. This table contains two data fields. Theese fields will be populated by the users when they will fill in the specific content (example: to specific a publish date for a news). Now i didn't used the Date contributed module on purpose, cause i needed that theese two fields were on the same row in the database table for other reasons.

The hook_schema defines the two fields this way:

```
'pubblish_date' => array(
    'description' => t('The pubblish date for the single news'),
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
  'unpublish_date' => array(
    'description' => t('The unpublish date for the single news'),
    'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
    'not null' => FALSE,
  ),
```

The table is created correctly in the database, but i always get theese advice messages:

Field news_board.pubblish_date: no Schema type for mysql type datetime.
Field news_board.unpublish_date: no Schema type for mysql type datetime.
news_board.pubblish_date: no  type for Schema type :normal.
Field news_board.pubblish_date: no Schema type for type .
news_board.unpublish_date: no  type for Schema type :normal.
Field news_board.unpublish_date: no Schema type for type .

Seems strange to me cause I red on the documentation to use the mysql_type specification in order to store the datetime format in mysql database.

I know that Drupal supports natively timestamps and if you want to store a different date format you have to use specific definitions like mysql_type or pgsql_type according on the database yuo are using.

In discussions I found online lot of people used mysql_type definition and from what I seen they solved the problem, so why it doesn't work for me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should provide a fallback type (`varchar`) for the case that the database is *not* mysql.

```
'pubblish_date' => array(
  'description' => t('The pubblish date for the single news'),
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => FALSE,
),
'unpublish_date' => array(
  'description' => t('The unpublish date for the single news'),
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => FALSE,
),
```

However, the messages you see come from the [Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) module. This problem is already recorded as [issue #468644](http://drupal.org/node/468644).

The implementation of the mysql datetime in your schema is fine. You can safely ignore these messages.  I would say that these "advice messages" are caused by a bug in the Schema module.

Comment: Hi Gisle, thank you for the answer. I just did the modification you suggested and yes, it creates the table in the database but i still got this adivices: 
`•Field news_board.pubblish_date: no Schema type for mysql type datetime.
•Field news_board.unpublish_date: no Schema type for mysql type datetime.`

Comment: Yes I know, I have disabled and uninstalled it but the result is the same. The core version I'm using is the 7.22. I want to specify that I have the schema module also installed. The advices mentioned appear when i try to inspect the schema of the database with this module. Honestly i did not try to check if they appese also in other part of the admin interface. I'm also wondering if I can ignore this messages at this point and continuing building the module. I don't know if this will affect the functionality of the module itself.

Comment: OK, thank you so much for your time Gisle, you saved lot of mine!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a record type not included in the officially supported list of types , you can specify a type for each database backend.

In this case, you can leave out the type parameter, but be advised that your schema will fail to load on backends that do not have a type specified. A possible solution can be to use the "text" type as a fallback.
(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/group/schemaapi/8.2.x)

`'submit_date' => array(
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'mysql_type' => 'datet',
)`