# create a datetime field with data module

Tags: datetime

I have installed the data module in order to create some data tables, but I have noticed that there is no datetime type given in the user interface, so how can I add some datatime fields to my data tables with the use od data module?

Answer (score 1):

To get date and time data types in the Drupal that can be used in fields, etc., install the [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date) module in addition to the [Data](https://drupal.org/project/data) module.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails,
as a dirty workaround, you can set the date field to be a varchar, with the exact date/time format you want. It is not the best solution ever, but seemed to be working properly in a project I did while ago.
I couldn't run Date field as well and as far as I remember, there was a reported bug, leading towards the "Schema" module.

Comment: Yes, there is a known bug in the Schema module that produces some not-fatal error messages, see  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69737/how-to-implement-a-mysql-date-or-datetime-field-correctly-in-hook-schema for details.  You can ignore  those.