# Why am I getting this error for the schema I define in my module?

Tags: 7, database

I'm building a module for Drupal 7, but I have troubles with my schema, and I don't understand why.

This is my schema.

```
$schema['table_name'] = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            ),
            'nid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            ),
            'oid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            ),
            'start_time' => array(
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'not null' => false
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'not null' => false
            ),
            'duration' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            )
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
        'unique keys' => array('id')
    );
```

I get this error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NULL DEFAULT NULL,  `end_time` NULL DEFAULT NULL, `duration` INT
>   unsigned NOT ' at line 5: CREATE  TABLE {table_name} ( `id` INT
>   unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `nid` INT  unsigned NOT NULL, `oid`
>   INT unsigned NOT NULL, `start_time` NULL DEFAULT  NULL, `end_time`
>   NULL DEFAULT NULL, `duration` INT unsigned NOT NULL, PRIMARY  KEY
>   (`id`), UNIQUE KEY `0` () ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
>   utf8;  Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2717 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/www/includes/database/database.inc).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I've found out Drupal 7 no longer supports the `datetime` type and to use this type you must use the key 'mysql_type', however I'm still getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix it. I've altered 2 things from my original schema, the first issue was that Drupal 7 no longer supports `'type' => 'datetime'`, instead use `'mysql_type' => 'datetime'`. The second was `'unique keys' => array('id')`, I removed this and everything works correctly.

#### Solution...

```
$schema['table_name'] = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            ),
            'nid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            ),
            'oid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            ),
            'start_time' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
                'size' => 'normal',
                'not null' => false
            ),
            'end_time' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
                'size' => 'normal',
                'not null' => false
            ),
            'duration' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => true,
                'not null' => true,
                'length' => 11
            )
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
        'mysql_engine' => 'InnoDB'
    );
```

Comment: `unique keys` takes a nested array, so `'unique keys' => array('idx_id_uniq' => array('id'));`. But it doesn't make sense to have the primary and unique keys set for the same single column, as primary keys already have a unique constraint

Answer (score -1):

Try this for Drupal7,

```
'pubblish_date' => array(
  'description' => t('The pubblish date for the single news'),
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => FALSE,
),
'unpublish_date' => array(
  'description' => t('The unpublish date for the single news'),
  'type' => 'varchar',
  'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
  'not null' => FALSE,
),
```

Comment: Thanks @shrish, similar solution to what I've just posted. An issue here maybe that whilst using the Type Varchar you may also need to include a Length value.

Comment: Some elaboration on the problem and why this solution works rather than 'here is a fix for your specific code' would be much more appreciated.

Comment: This is also a word-for-word copy paste from a similar issue.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69737/how-to-implement-a-mysql-date-or-datetime-field-correctly-in-hook-schema